# How to pass value to the $(document).ready(function(){}) after clicking submit function-JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hi I have a form in my page, which i accepts a single text field.

```
<form name="cname" id ="cname1">
        Last name: <input type="text" id="lname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After clicking the submit function, I need to pass the value of the text field to `$( document ).ready(function() {})`.Document.ready function will call another function with parameters like this `displayRecords(10, 1,clientName);`. Is there any way to send the value to function. I have coded like this, and its not taking the value.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var clientName=$("#lname").val();
    alert(clientName);
    displayRecords(10, 1,clientName
});
```

When i type some value and click submit, its not taking the value from the text box.

Comment: Why do you want to send value to document.ready on button click. You can write another method for the button click

Comment: @Unnie:I needed to call the same `displayRecords()` on the page loading without that clientName value assigned , so I put that function in document.ready function, and tried to assign the clientName on clicking the submit button.

Now I found out , that simply calling the function will call the function on page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` runs when the page is first loaded. If you want something to happen when you click the submit button, use a submit handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cname1").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the normal form submission
        var clientName = $("#lname").val();
        alert(clientName);
        displayRecords(10, 1, clientName);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's an event handler, like `.change()` and `.click()`. It's triggered when you try to submit the form.

Comment: I guess you need to learn the basics of jQuery event handling. Get a jQuery book or look for a web tutorial, I'm not going to try to teach that.

Comment: :Yeah sure. I said without understanding that function, i tried to run. Now i Got it. Thank you